# It does not allow me to continue the installation of SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

When installing SQL Server 2008 R2, it does not let me continue the process.
I only get to the point of auxiliary files.

I do not see the continuation.

What I can do?

[image]

[image][image]

It does not advance

Comment: click `Install` ?

Comment: when clicking, it does not advance